# How to get number of rows in sas dataset in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sas

Is there any way to get the no of rows in sas dataset("xxxx.sas7bdat") without actually reading the dataset in python. The reason for not reading the sas dataset is, it is huge.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is a "sas dataset"?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I am still not sure I know what a sas dataset is. But if you want to count the number of rows in any file, you can use the `wc -l` shell command. You can invoke it from within python by using the os module. Actually, I'll just put this in an answer.

Comment: Did you try the sas7bdat package?  It claims to read the header, but it doesn't look like it reads the number of observations from the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do this by simply counting the rows in the file by using the `wc -l` shell command and reading it into a variable:

```
import os
>>> import os
>>> stream = os.popen('wc -l example.txt')
>>> output = stream.read()
>>> output
'       3 example.txt\n'
```

You could further tokenize the output to get number of rows as a variable:

```
>>> output.split()
['3', 'example.txt']
>>> output.split()[0]
'3'
>>> int(output.split()[0])
3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You cannot count the number of "lines" in a binary format file. That does not make any sense.